# Function Overload Resolution - Between Const Lvalue Ref and Rvalue Ref

Tags: rvalue-reference, overload-resolution

I came across the following C++ code -

```
class C {
public:
  C() { std::cout << "1"; }
  C(C const&) { std::cout << "2"; }
  C(C&&) { std::cout << "3"; }
  ~C() { std::cout << "4"; }
};

void g(C const&) {
  std::cout << "7";
}

void g(C&&) {
  std::cout << "8";
}

C&& f(C&& c) {
  g(c);
  return std::move(c);
}

int main() {
  g(f(C()));
}
```

The program calls g() twice. Both times I expect g(C&&) to be called, but this is not what happened.

When I ran the code g(C const&) was called the 1st time. The 2nd time g(C&&) was called.
ChatGPT agreed with me that g(C&&) should be called the first time too.
So why is the result different?